# meaning: "nothing so much as a dictionary"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "nothing so much as" mean in the following? Is it natural?

Ricky wants **nothing so much as** a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

It means Ricky wants a dictionary more than anything else.

It's rather poetic but absolutely natural.